# Prove or disprove(Sets theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove: If $A ⊆ \overline{(B ∪ C)}$ and $B ⊆ \overline{(A ∪ C)}$, then $B = \emptyset $

---

I am very grateful to you for all of your help.

Comment: Draw a picture  ..

Comment: What about $A=[1]$ , $B=[2]$ , $C=[3]$ ?

Comment: A more general counterexample is that no two of the sets $A,B,C$ have a common element and $B$ is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think what they are saying.

$B\subset \overline {(A\cup C)}$.  That means $B$ is entirely contained outside $A$ and $C$.

$A \subset \overline {(B\cup C)}$.  That means $A$ is entirely contained outside $B$ and $C$.

Okay, cool, the sets are entirely separate.  $B= \{birds\}$ and $A = \{automobiles\}$ and $C = \{cupcakes\}$.  That works.

$B \subset\overline{A\cup C}$ means no bird is either an automobile nor a cupcake, and $A\subset\overline{B\cup C}$ means no automobile is a bird or a cupcake.  Can't argue with that.

So does that mean $B = \emptyset$, that $B$ has no members, that there are no such thing as birds?  No.  It does not mean that.

====

Believe it or not I didn't notice $A$ is for $A$utomobile, $B$ is for $B$ird, and $C$ is for $C$upcake until after I had chosen all three.  .... Okay, you don't believe it.. I wouldn't either.... but it's true.